# Finish pending store transactions?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes-store

How can someone finish or remove any pending store transaction?

A client tested an app IAP with a test user, the purchase didn't finish, and the user expired, he cannot login with the user anymore, and now the system is always trying to make him log in with the old user, and when trying to re-purchase the IAP the transaction gets cancelled because of the previous one.

The only way I know for solving this is restoring the system, but that's a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Tell the client to log out of this user account in Settings -> Store -> Apple ID.

Then the app should prompt for a new username when you attempt a purchase.

Comment: I think I already tried that back in the day and that didn't work. Dunno, will tell him.

Comment: Have you tried doing the above and also deleting the app from the home screen and reinstalling? I can't see how any purchases could be carried over in this case...

Comment: Even reinstalling the app wouldn't work. That's something I'm pretty sure from my tests months ago. Back in the day the only work around I found was to restore the whole system. I know I'm not the only one to suffer from this problem, but never saw how other people solved this issue.

Comment: Hmm. The only weirdness I had with in-app purchases was when I wasn't calling `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];` in `-paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` for every state but `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing`. Are you doing that?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it, but it happened that the transaction could not be finished, and then the test user account expired.

Comment: Damn. Well sorry I can't be of more help! I've found the IAP framework very irritating to work with during development as well.